# Tomcat 9 failed on deployment of Spring Boot WAR

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, tomcat9

I am attempting to build a war file from my basic spring boot application. The application will build a WAR successfully with `mvn package`, however, when I go to deploy it to my Tomcat 9 server I get the message:

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/kevthedev] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/kevthedev]]]
```

The objective is to build a basic spring boot application and deploy it to a Tomcat 9 server. The spring boot application will not have an embedded Tomcat server instead use the external Tomcat server 9 I built.

Below is my `POM.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.kev.developer</groupId>
    <artifactId>kevthedev</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>kevthedev</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And my class file for the main app is below:

```java
package com.kev.developer;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class KevthedevApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(KevthedevApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(KevthedevApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Attached are my logs

```
2018-10-09 16:03:51.353  INFO 798 --- [o-8080-exec-114] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-12 - Starting...
2018-10-09 16:03:51.566  INFO 798 --- [o-8080-exec-114] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-12 - Start completed.
2018-10-09 16:03:51.627  INFO 798 --- [o-8080-exec-114] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-10-09 16:03:51.652  INFO 798 --- [o-8080-exec-114] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
2018-10-09 16:03:51.813  INFO 798 --- [o-8080-exec-114] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-10-09 16:03:51.814  INFO 798 --- [o-8080-exec-114] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-10-09 16:03:51.842  WARN 798 --- [o-8080-exec-114] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
2018-10-09 16:03:51.842  INFO 798 --- [o-8080-exec-114] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-12 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-10-09 16:03:51.869  INFO 798 --- [o-8080-exec-114] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-12 - Shutdown completed.
2018-10-09 16:03:51.921  INFO 798 --- [o-8080-exec-114] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
2018-10-09 16:03:51.926 ERROR 798 --- [o-8080-exec-114] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Comment: There should be more logs in catalina.out or standard out log files under logs folder. Analyse them or paste them here..

Comment: I attached the logs to the question above.

Comment: Why do you have to deploy a Spring Boot app as a WAR on Tomcat?  I'd recommend deploying an executable JAR that has Tomcat running inside it.  Invert the problem.

Comment: @duffymo I have a requirement to set up the environments using Docker containers. A tomcat server is associated with the environment. Therefore I have to remove the embedded tomcat and deploy just the application to the environments. If it wasn't for that then I would always embed the tomcat.

Comment: If you run in Docker, all you need is a Java JVM to run the Spring Boot executable on.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to include a dependency. All instructions say that you can configure just the package to war, add the tomcat dependency and then update your main class to override. However, this is not the only thing.

I needed to add the following dependency into my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Error from catalina was:

```
grep "^$(date -I)" /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out


Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the main Spring boot class to `SpringBootServletInitializer` resolved my problem:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
   return application.sources(Application.class);
  }
}
```